# Cant use action attribute in form

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, backend, crud

So I am making a crud application. But i have a problem in my edit part. I setted up the edit view and the action to the update function, where I setted up the update too. But when I hit submit it wont redirect me to the page and it wont update, it will stay to the edit page, and its not giving me any error!

This is my form(don't mind the style):

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('profile.update', $user->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')
            <div class="col-8 offset-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Title</label>

                    <input id="title"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                           name="title"
                           value="{{$user->profile->title}}"
                           required autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                    @error('title')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                     </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Description</label>

                    <input id="description"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                           name="description"
                           value="{{$user->profile->description}}"
                           required autocomplete="description" autofocus>

                    @error('description')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                     </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="url" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Url</label>

                    <input id="url"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                           name="url"
                           value="{{$user->profile->url}}"
                           required autocomplete="url" autofocus>

                    @error('url')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                     </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Profile Image</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                    @error('image')
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="row pt-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-25">Save Profile</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', [ProfilesController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function update(User $user)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'url'=>'url',
            'image'=>'file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,giv,svg'
        ]);

        auth()->user()->profile()->update($data);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', $user->id);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the validation in controller ?

Comment: Its still the same, I even tried to dd() and see what I get but it returns me to the same page (edit)!

Comment: why you ar using `patch` ? As I know `put` method is for updating request , even `post`

Comment: Patch is used too! I'll try it without patch only with post.

Comment: I tried post and i tried put it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

So I ran the code to display the validation errors:
[image]

And I got this:
[image]

So I didn't have a valid URL and than I fixed it to this, now I can update:
[image]